# data cannot be saved in form

Tags: python, django

data  cannot be saved in  form.I wrote html like

```
<form  action="/app/save" method="POST">
                <input id="classname" name="classname">
                <input id="score" name="score">
                <input id="course" name="course">
            <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Student

class SaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("classname", "score", "course")
```

in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def save(request):
    save_form = SaveForm(request.POST or None)
    print(save_form.is_valid())
    if request.method == "POST" and save_form.is_valid():
        item = save_form.save(commit=False)
        classname = request.POST.get("classname", "")
        score = request.POST.get("score", "")
        course = request.POST.get("course", "")


        item.classname = classname
        item.score = score
        item.course = course

        item.save()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

in models.py
from django.db import models

```
class Student(models.Model):
    classname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When I run this codes ,put data A in classname& 80 in score&Math in course of html and put SEND button,save method can be called but data cannot be saved.print(save_form.is_valid()) shows False.I really cannot understand why I can't send data.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Comment: Add your models and what you're inputting into the form as data. Can't help you without that info

Comment: If you inspect `form.errors` it will show you why the form failed to validate. The way you are handling the form data is also not how you should do it - you are duplicating the logic performed by [`ModelForm.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) when you reassign all the values manually.

Comment: @OwenHempel I add some infos.If you know something, please help me.

Comment: @solarissmoke  form.errors shows

Comment: @solarissmoke `<ul class="errorlist"><li>classname<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required</li></ul></li><li>score<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required</li></ul></li><li>course<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required</li></ul></ul>`

Comment: @solarissmoke I wrote all filed but this error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay a few things here;

- Why is score a charfield? If it's a %, shouldn't it be an int?
- Student model doesn't have any foreign keys, so there's really no need to use `commit = false` in your save.
- Creating inputs for each item on your form in html is definitely the long way to do it. The best way to do this in your html is simply to use {{form}}. To do this, you'll need to pass the form as a variable in `context` in your `views.py`.

Without being mean, are you very early in to the django beginner tutorial? If so, I would recommend moving forward through that before trying to continue your current project. It'll really help you. Here's what I would suggest as a views.py

```
    def save(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
          save_form = SaveForm(request.POST)
          print(save_form.is_valid())
          if(save_form.is_valid()):
            save_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('New-destination-URL')
    save_form = SaveForm()
    context['form'] = save_form
    return render(request, context, 'index.html')
```

and in index.html:

```
form  action="/app/save" method="POST">
{{form}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it wrong, you have to handle both situations - when you are on page at first time, and time when form is filled with data.

Try to change your views to this :

```
if request.method == "POST":
    save_form = SaveForm(request.POST)
    ...
else:
    save_form = SaveForm()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'save_form': save_form)
```

and then try to put this in template:

```
<form  action="/app/save" method="POST">
  {{ save_form.as_p }}    
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.I wrote your codes, but same error happens.Is there any idea ?